# Integrals of Legendre polynomial and a rational function

Tags: definite-integrals, legendre-polynomials

Is there are analytic expression of the following definite integral?

$$
\int_{-1}^1 x^\alpha (1-x^2)^{\beta} P_l(x) P_m(x) \text{d}x
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.